# Attach 2 Scripts with same Parent to the same GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I did as the title suggests but Unity seems to add all variables to the script that is higher in the hirachy. Does somebody have a fix?[image]

public abstract class Enemy : Entity
{ ...}
public abstract class Unit : Entity
{...}

```
public void GenerateCharacters(int x, int y, GameObject c, int i)
{
    GameObject go = Instantiate(c) as GameObject;
    Entity e = go.GetComponent<Entity>();
    //StartCoroutine(e.SpawnAnim());


    if (i == 0)
    {
        Unit u = c.GetComponent<Unit>();
        u.InitializeUnits();
        u.healthBarEnemy = healthBarEnemy;
        u.healthBarAlly = healthBarAlly;
        u.healthMeter = healthbarMeter;
        GeneratePosition(u, x, y);
        u.InitiateGrid(grid);
        u.PlayerChange(gamePhase);
    }
    else
    {
        Enemy en = c.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        en.InitializeEnemies();
        en.healthBarEnemy = healthBarEnemy;
        en.healthBarAlly = healthBarAlly;
        en.healthMeter = healthbarMeter;
        GeneratePosition(e, x, y);
        en.InitiateGrid(grid);
        en.PlayerChange(gamePhase);
    }
    Debug.Log(unitList.Count);
}
```

Comment: You will have to provide further information. Such as code or screenshots of the issue. It is hard to work with without knowing the setup.

Comment: You are right my bad. I added some code.

Comment: Might want to look into this. I'm not sure if it still holds true though.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/07/why-doesnt-c-support-multiple-inheritance/

Comment: You seem to be instantiating the GameObject go, but you still use the incoming parameter object c (GameObject). Could this have a influence on the issue of urs? The c.GetComponent<Unit>(); should maybe be go.GetComponent<Unit>(); and the same for the .GetComponent<Enemy>();

Comment: First, `Enemy` and `Unit` are abstract.  If Unity had "realtime" error checking it wouldn't let us pull abstract classes into the Inspector. Logically, you cannot create an instance of an abstract class.  As a test, remove the `abstract` from your classes.  Also, `InitializeEnemies` and `InitializeUnits` should also be abstract, no?

Comment: If you look at the screenshot i did not pull abstract classes into the inspector but rather their children. Also initialize Units should not be abstract no.

Comment: @FNTNBWIH It‘s not inheriting from mulitple classes. Multiple classes are inheriting from one Parent class

Comment: @Skdy You are right. That is wrong but I don‘t know how this caused this specific Bug. I will fix it and let you know what happened.

Comment: `c` is a public object hes instantiating from, not his variable. he is right in accessing go, not c. consider c a template. he dosn't want to change his template. he wants to copy it and change the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @skdy for the answer. He was right i should have used go and not c. thank you